# Select items that share identical values in another field

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Sorry I am quite new to mysql, so please bear with me. Suppose I have

```
main                  other
 teacherloh@gmail.com        1
 teacherken@gmail.com        2
 teacherhoh@gmail.com        3
 teacherjoe@gmail.com        2
 teachersoh@gmail.com        4
 teacheroh@gmail.com        5
```

Since teacherken@gmail.com and teacherjoe@gmail.com have the same `other` value which is 2. I would like to select and return those two emails.

I tried using

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main) as main_set, other
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY other
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main)='A,B';
```

which does not work for my case.

Any idea?

Comment: It's hard to be sure from your question, but it seems that instead of `HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main)='A,B'` you either want `WHERE other = 2` OR `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT main) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking a simple `where` suffices:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM yourTable *
WHERE t.other = 2;
```

If you are looking for duplicates, you can do:

```
SELECT other, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT main) as main_set
FROM yourTable t
GROUP BY other
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT main) > 1;
```

I don't know if the `DISTINCT` is necessary.  If your original table can't have duplicates, then remove the `DISTINCT`.